# How to take the screenshot of part of Google Maps use JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas

On my page, there is a container which use Google Maps API to display a map, there is a button below it, user can drag the map to a position, then click the button, I'd like to take the screenshot of the map displayed in the container now and show it in a canvas. Is it possible to do this with pure JavaScript?

Just need to support Chrome

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It will be hard to do without browser support. But you can use Google Static Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example

---

There is some projects to draw HTML DOM to canvas:

- HTML2Canvas: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/index.html
- jsFeedback: http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

You can also integrate javascript with some server-side solution (using webkit) for example [phantomjs](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/)

Code example: (read more [here](http://pielmeier.blogspot.com/2011/02/headless-html-page-rendering-with.html))

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.google.com', function() {

    page.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 768};
    page.render('screenshot.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

---

If you need only chrome solution for specific range of users you can write your own chrome extension to do this: [Taking screenshot using javascript for chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573956/taking-screenshot-using-javascript-for-chrome-extensions)

Comment: only chrome need to be supported

Comment: Are there any updates on this?  Does API 3 give an ability to do this?

Comment: I tried using HTML2Canvas API, but it shows a blank image when taking screenshot of map. Dont know why

Comment: There is a restriction for Google static map API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro#url-size-restriction "Maps Static API URLs are restricted to 8192 characters in size"