# How to take screenshot of a Google map using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I want to take a 'screenshot' of a google map in my html file using JavaScript.

The map is currently loading in `div` tags, so I am not able to get image using this `<div>` tag.

But if I can load it in canvas `<canvas>` then I can take a screenshot of it very easily, can anybody tell me solution for this problem - that is, how can I load a google map in canvas.

Or is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take the screenshot of part of Google Maps use JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590620/how-to-take-the-screenshot-of-part-of-google-maps-use-javascript)

Comment: Were you able to take screenshot using HTML2canvas of a map? if so, please tell how did you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using one of those scripts:

- html2canvas http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
- jsFeedback http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/

Credits to [How to take the screenshot of part of Google Maps use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590620/how-to-take-the-screenshot-of-part-of-google-maps-use-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use google [maps image api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview)?

Comment: You're right but I don't have fixed latitude and longitude, place can be changed by user any time so I need to use it.

Comment: if user changes the place - you can always retrieve coordinates from the map itself

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware about it, can you please suggest me any thing regarding this?

Comment: have a look at [gmaps](https://github.com/HPNeo/gmaps) library and specifically - [this example](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html) - it shows you how to get coordinates from address

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. E.g: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=18&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C42.65655554361449,21.165063181948653

Comment: @Shpat Your link refference throw an error, this might help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview

Comment: what if I have some layers on the map, cant use the static api