# Save Google Map (placed in an iframe) as an image using HTML/Javascript Windows Metro Apps

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps, iframe, windows-8

I'm designing a Windows 8 Metro Style Application using HTML/Javascript and I'm using an iframe to place my Google Map in it. I need to save the current map view as an image. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Post your code which you use for Google map

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that

Try the below things

1. [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
2. [JSFeedback](http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/)

Already answer is here, thanks to [Save Google Map As image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590620/how-to-take-the-screenshot-of-part-of-google-maps-use-javascript)

Hope this helps...

Comment: I've tried html2canvas but from the map all I get is [this](http://prntscr.com/456epf)