# Print map image/Google street view (Using Google Static Map API)

Tags: api, dictionary

Problem Statement: A user will enter a property address or Lat/long based on that we need an image of Google Maps to print on a document for the end user so the user better understands the property location and nearby properties likewise, parks, lakes, etc. Please see the below criteria,

1. Print a Google Map image on the flyer/document.
2. Size should be 2000*1051
3. Image should display the Parcel boundaries.
4. Using Google Static map API.

We highly appreciate your advice, and the possible solution to achieve keep in mind the above requirement.

Technology: PHP Laravel Framework and Maps API

Please let us know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us in which language you try to do that, but I think it can help you :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.google.com', function() {
  page.viewportSize = {width: 2000, height: 1051};
  page.render('screenshot.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

[How to take the screenshot of part of Google Maps use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590620/how-to-take-the-screenshot-of-part-of-google-maps-use-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to do it using the Laravel framework.