# Chrome extension URL to work with all websites

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this *manifest.json* and inn `"matches":[]`, I am suppose to put in the URL this Chrome extension will work on. Is it possible to have this work with *any* website?

*manifest.json*:

```
{
  "name" : "OpenTok Screen Sharing",
  "author": "TokBox, Inc.",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "34",
  "description" : "This Chrome extension is developed primary for http://tokbox.com/. It doesn't do anything except capture content of your screen.",
  "homepage_url": "http://tokbox.com/",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background-script.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
   "js": [ "content-script.js" ],
   "all_frames": true,
   "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"]
  }],
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo16.png",
    "48": "logo48.png",
    "128": "logo128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon.png"
  ]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096482/what-does-http-https-and-all-urls-mean-in-the-context-of-ch

Comment: The documentation for [`matches`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matches) Says "See [**Match Patterns**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for more details on the syntax of these strings".  [**Match Patterns**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) explains what you need. If it is still unclear after reading the documentation and the linked duplicate, please ask another question which details what is not clear to you.