# Escaping of angle brackets in manifest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to understand why some extensions use escaping for `<all_urls>` angle brackets, whereas another extensions don't.

Some manifests don't use escaping at all, some use escaping for opening angle bracket, and some for both. Examples:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
]

"permissions": [
    "\u003Call_urls>"
]

and even

"permissions": [
    "\u003Call\u005Furls\u003E"
]
```

What's the purpose behind these replacements and should / should not I escape it?

---

Update. As live examples, here are few extensions offered by Google, which are using escaping: [Share to Classroom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-to-classroom/adokjfanaflbkibffcbhihgihpgijcei), [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) and [High Contrast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph). There are probably more. These 3 is just a result of my own brief research.

Also, here is assumption that escaping is for validation ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096482/what-does-http-https-and-all-urls-mean-in-the-context-of-ch)):

> Although the manifest.json should be Unicode-encoded, I've seen a lot of extensions escaping the `<`, `_` and `>`, to their's equivalent Unicode-format of `"\u003Call\u005Furls\u003E"`. I've asked around, and apparently some developers have used validation mechanism, which then validated the JSON "invalid" because of those characters.

But, Google extensions which I gave as live examples, escapes only opening angle bracket, that is:

```
\u003Call_urls>
```

That's why, from my point of view, the quote above doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Because they blindly copypaste some ancient broken example produced by a broken site script that could not properly balance quoting/unquoting of the special symbols. There's no need to escape these.

Comment: @wOxxOm For example, [High Contrast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph). This extension is marked as "By Google". And I see `\u003Call_urls>` in it's manifest.

Comment: You'd be amazed by the amount of legacy/buggy code produced by the mighty google.

Comment: BTW you can open an issue on https://crbug.com and point out the unnecessary escaping in those extensions which confuses some developers who use buggy JSON validators. Note, the documentation [isn't crippled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, it's a good idea.