# Is there a way to use the screenshot API that chrome developer tools provide in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

https://www.howtogeek.com/423558/how-to-take-full-page-screenshots-in-google-chrome-without-using-an-extension/
The link shows the way to take screenshot of the entire page in chrome using the chrome developer tools. Is there An API of any kind that I can use in a chrome extension so that the screenshot command gets executed when the extension is clicked.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122630/) in the linked topic that uses the `chrome.debugger` API is the one that mimics devtools internal behavior.

Comment: okay...i will kook into it