# How to make a screenshot google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am trying to create a chrome extension that captures the screen of a webpage and makes an ajax call with the captured picture.

I want the screen capture to work like a capture area screenshot in the chrome developer tools.

Question.

1. Is there a way to call the capture area screenshot function of chrome developer tools from javascript code?
2. Can I get a rough idea of ​​what language the capture area screenshot function of Chrome Developer Tools is made in?

Comment: In the interest of content quality, duplicate questions are not permitted. Please research your inquiry before posting in accordance with [ask]. This is a duplicate of [Taking screenshot using javascript for chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573956/taking-screenshot-using-javascript-for-chrome-extensions)

Comment: A few clarifying questions anyway: “*Is there a way to call the capture area screenshot function of chrome developer tools from javascript code?*” Why does it need to invoke the functionality contained in the developer tools *specifically*? “*Can I get a rough idea of ​​what language the capture area screenshot function of Chrome Developer Tools is made in?*” You can - run it through a language-agnostic OCR tool and use a language detection API on the result to get the language of the page you’ve taken a screenshot of.