# How do websites like jam.dev achieve their screenshotting functionality?

Tags: javascript, screenshot

does anyone know how websites like jam.dev achieve their click and drag screenshotting functionality?

I am trying to create a tool which involves screenshotting on the client side and my preferred way was to implement it in a similar fashion. Is anyone kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Some things I have tried and researched, but these don't provide the exact results I want:

- html2canvas and other libraries that use svg and foreign object - these just don't produce consistent results.
- rendering server side with puppeteer - it would be much better if the screenshotting could be achieved client side.
- using webRTC - asking for permission and having the user select a screen/window is just not very intuitive.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I don't believe the OP wants to make a chrome extension, just a webpage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers share api for extensions that allows making a screenshot

Accoding to [this answwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574782/5089567)

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (image) {
   // You can add that image HTML5 canvas, or Element.
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, the whole time I've been looking I never thought to include chrome extension in the search.. Thank you!